# How can I get more accuracy in calculating PI?

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to calculate pi using numbers between 1 through 30 with this formula below

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYtUE.png)

Here is what I've done so far:

```
int k, outside = 0;
double inside = 0;

cout << "Please enter in a value for k..." << endl;
cin >> k;

while (k < 1 || k > 30)
{

    cout << "Invalid --- k must be >=1 and <=30" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter in a value for k..." << endl;
    cin >> k;

}

outside = pow(2, k);
    
for (int loopNum = 1; loopNum < k; loopNum++)
{
        
    inside = sqrt(2 + inside);

}

inside = sqrt(2 - inside);
double ApproxPI = outside * inside;

cout << fixed << setprecision(20);
cout << "Approximation of PI = " << ApproxPI << endl;
```

I feel like I did the formula correctly, but the results aren't accurate. Also, when 'k' is set to 29 or 30, it only gives out the value 0. Does anyone know what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: 64bit floating point numbers have precision of about 15.9 decimal digits...

Comment: 16 significant digits accuracy sounds about right for `double` math. The more math you do on floating point numbers, the more the error accumulates (some even say that [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/7976805)). A few print statements sprinkled around show why the result is `0` for input `k = 29`: https://godbolt.org/z/EsafMzGvT

Comment: Is long double an option?

Answer (score 5):

Each `sqrt()` computation incurs 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) error.  Each addition can incur much more. [@Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen)
Yet it is the severe cancellation of precision with `2 - inside` that is the killer.

Although the formula mathematical converges, the raw code implementation does not due to accumulated errors.

`inside` approaches 2.0 and `2 - inside` eventually that difference becomes 0.0.  As the difference becomes smaller and smaller,  the precision in the difference becomes less.  Thus the best pi approximation occurs when `inside` has about half its most significant binary digits all set to 1 so the value is just less than 2.0, and the remaining digits form the basis for pi.  I'd expect the best approximation to be within about 1/2 the usual 16 decimal digits of `double`.

> Does anyone know what I might be doing incorrectly?

To get a better answer, code needs extended math or a different formula.

---

C example demo code

```
long long ULP_diff(double x, double ref) {
  union {
      double d;
      long long ll;
  } ux, uref;
  ux.d = x;
  uref.d = ref;
  return ux.ll - uref.ll;
}

double pip(int k) {
  double outside = pow(2, k);

  double inside = 0;
  for (int loopNum = 1; loopNum < k; loopNum++) {
    inside = sqrt(2 + inside);
  }
  inside = sqrt(2 - inside);

  double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
  double ApproxPI = outside * inside;
  printf("%2d %a %a %15lld %.16f\n", k, pi, ApproxPI, ULP_diff(ApproxPI, pi), ApproxPI);
  return ApproxPI;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int i = 5; i < 32; i++)
    pip(i);
}
```

Output: Smallest ULP distance at iteration 14.

```
 5 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.91f65f10dd7f5p+1  -2840637887779 3.1403311569547392
 6 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.92155f7a3665ap+1   -710223644350 3.1412772509327569
 7 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921d1fcdec626p+1   -177559922418 3.1415138011441455
 8 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921f0fe670767p+1    -44390229425 3.1415729403678827
 9 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921f8beccbd5ep+1    -11097567162 3.1415877252799609
10 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921faaee60d6fp+1     -2774409129 3.1415914215046352
11 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb2aee1ba8p+1      -693506416 3.1415923456110768
12 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb49eceff7p+1      -173489441 3.1415925765450043
13 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb5190a222p+1       -45320950 3.1415926334632482
14 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb546e04f1p+1         2742233 3.1415926548075892
15 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb532811eap+1       -18619182 3.1415926453212153
16 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb4e1045cep+1      -104064842 3.1415926073757197
17 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fb76cea693p+1       579500411 3.1415929109396727
18 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fc19c82711p+1      3313760761 3.1415941251951911
19 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fd5fbb1baap+1      8782278290 3.1415965537048196
20 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.921fd5fbb1baap+1      8782278290 3.1415965537048196
21 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.922261df7a054p+1    183772607292 3.1416742650217575
22 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.9227799aa8796p+1    533740280446 3.1418296818892015
23 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.923bd7e25164dp+1   1933437888821 3.1424512724941338
24 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.923bd7e25164dp+1   1933437888821 3.1424512724941338
25 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.94c583ada5b53p+1  46578493959739 3.1622776601683795
26 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.94c583ada5b53p+1  46578493959739 3.1622776601683795
27 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1.bb67ae8584caap+1 726225619525522 3.4641016151377544
28 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x1p+2 1932961502712552 4.0000000000000000
29 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x0p+0 -4614256656552045848 0.0000000000000000
30 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x0p+0 -4614256656552045848 0.0000000000000000
31 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 0x0p+0 -4614256656552045848 0.0000000000000000
```